# Remove file dropzone js laravel error 500

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I'am using dropzone js to upload multiple images (dropzone programmatically).

Upload files, it's ok.

But when I remove a file, some error occurred:

- 500 Internal Server Error (Method App\Modules\Product\Controllers\ProductController::delete does not exist - I don't have delete() method in controller - why?).
- Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

**My route**

```
Route::post('/adminks/products/delete/dropzone', 'ProductController@deleteImageDropzone')->name('be.delete.dropzone');
```

**My Controller**

```
public function deleteImageDropzone(Request $request) {
        $image = $request->filename;
        ProductImage::where(['image_name' => $image, 'model' => 'Product', 'module' => 'Product'])->delete();
        $path = public_path().'/uploads/images/product/product/'.$image;
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            unlink($path);
        }
        return $image;
    }
```

**My JS**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzone_images", {
            url: "{{ route('be.upload.dropzone') }}",
            sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                var code = '{{ $code }}';
                formData.append('code', code);
            },
            paramName: 'others_image',
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            acceptedFiles: '.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif',
            dictRemoveFile: 'Xóa ảnh',
            init: function() {
                this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                    var name = file.upload.filename;
                    $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '{{ url('/adminks/products/delete/dropzone') }}',
                        data: { filename: name },
                        success: function (data){
                            console.log("File has been successfully removed!!");
                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }});
                    var fileRef;
                    return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ?
                        fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
                });
            }
        });
```

Any solution? All comments are respected!
Thanks so much!

Comment: So, you don't have a delete function, but you're trying to call it, and wondering why you get an error?

Comment: Thanks, @GregSchmidt . I had `deleteImageDropzone` function to delete image in My Controller

Comment: From the error, it seems like it's not finding that. I'm not familiar with Laravel's routing, but I'd guess that's where you should start.

Comment: Thank you. But, I checked more time. If route not found, error 404 is returned

Comment: Can you get a stack trace somehow that shows exactly where it's at when you get the 500 error?

Comment: Yes, `{message: "Method App\Modules\Product\Controllers\ProductController::delete does not exist.",…}
message: "Method App\Modules\Product\Controllers\ProductController::delete does not exist."
exception: "BadMethodCallException"
file: "E:\Web\OSPanel\domains\kitagawa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php"
line: 68`

Comment: That's just the error message. A stack trace would show where that error happened, which might give clues about what is trying to call a function that doesn't exist.